# Date picker issue in SSRS reports hosted in WPF application

Tags: wpf, reporting-services

We have hosted **SSRS** reports in a **WPF** application using **ReportViewer**.

Month selection in the date picker is not working properly. However the date selection through navigation buttons is working fine. The date picker is getting displayed as shown in the below image. On selecting any month returning the current date.

[image: SSRS 2008 report date picker]

It needs to work like in calendar control in WPF

[image: WPF calendar control]

Comment: Is the issue that it doesn't look the same?

Comment: No, the issue here is that it does not select the month

Comment: Apparently, it does work when i preview the report in SQL server BI studio

Comment: Yes, it will; its using newer technology in BI Studio. But when you deploy to a 2008R2 (or 2012/14) report server, your report is rendered using some very old HTML. As I said in my answer you have two choices: handle it via expression, or upgrade. To be honest, since 2008R2 went out of mainstream support over two years, you need to be planning for the latter anyway

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the problem is here. The DatePicker control returns a DateTime object, from which you can then determine the month of that date using a SSRS [expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137586(v=sql.105).aspx).

If you mean that the Reporting Services control in 2008 R2 isn't as pretty as WPF; its much older tech and there's nothing you can do about that apart from upgrade to SQL Server 2016.